# Rotate an Image at a select point

Tags: android, image, rotation

So I have a general image rotation issue.  I was able to find how to make the rotate and made it scale correctly, but now I would like to set it up so that the image rotates at the point the user touches.

Currently, once touch, the top of the image will rotate towards where the touch initially happened.  Is there anyway so that it will stay at the point touched on the image and rotate from that point?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should post some of the code you have tried, even if it doesn't work. It will be a big help to people who want to answer your question!

Comment: If your question has been answered, please post the solution as an answer, and accept it by clicking the check next to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my code.  Just had to take the initial degree when ACTION_DOWN was called and then offset the rotate by that degree during ACTION_MOVE.
Code posted below

```
        //Finds the initial degree where my finger is pressed. 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
            double arc = Math.atan2(event.getX() - v.getWidth()/2, v.getHeight()/2 - event.getY());
            initDegree = (float) Math.toDegrees(arc);
            setTitle("counter" + counter++);
            break;}
        // Using the Initial Degree change I offset the degrees to send to my rotate function.
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:{
            double arc = Math.atan2(event.getX() - v.getWidth()/2, v.getHeight()/2 - event.getY());
            float degrees = (float) Math.toDegrees(arc);
            rotate(degrees-initDegree);
            break;}
```